# Proper syntax & structure for 2 nesting foreach() loops after a var_dump()

Tags: php, foreach, nested-loops, var-dump, multidimensional-array

As en uneducated PHP person, I am beginning to confuse myself as I try to create & save a CSV file, made from data submitted from an online form.

I am running in to massive troubles trying to 'extract' the data from inputs after they have been posted to the PHP code/page

For this question's purpose, lets say that I have a total of 15 inputs, organized in 5 rows and 3 columns.

I received some suggestions to use var_dump() to create an array of the inputs.  This works just fine.  I was also told that after the var_dump(), I should build 2 nested foreach() loops , and it is here that I am befuddled.

Let's say that the table looks like this:
[image: example imput form]

The array that results from the var_dump() is like this:

```
array(5) { 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        ["A"]=> string(0) "" ["B"]=> string(0) "" ["C"]=> string(0) "" 
    }
    [2]=> array(3) {
        ["A"]=> string(0) "" ["B"]=> string(0) "" ["C"]=> string(0) ""
     }
    [3]=> array(3) {
        ["A"]=> string(0) "" ["B"]=> string(0) "" ["C"]=> string(0) ""
     }
    [4]=> array(3)
    {
        ["A"]=> string(0) "" ["B"]=> string(0) "" ["C"]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [5]=> array(3) {
        ["A"]=> string(0) "" ["B"]=> string(0) "" ["C"]=> string(0) ""
    }
}
```

Obviously the strlen() wouldn't be 0 when filled. The `[1]` etc. would be the rows, and the `["A"]` etc. would be the columns.

Now skipping ahead, the end game is to create a CSV structure that might look like:

```
Header One,Header Two,Header Three,
row1-column1,row1-column2,row1-column3,
row2-column1,row2-column2,row2-column3,
row3-column1,row3-column2,row3-column3,
row4-column1,row4-column2,row4-column3,
row5-column1,row5-column2,row5-column3,
```

I presume that I can figure out how to save the echoed output into a CSV file, but what I am asking is how to I extract the inputs from the array (provided the strlen() is >0)?

Again I received some tips on using two nested foreach loops.

I must be completely thick, but I can't get any foreach variations to echo anything at all.

Code utilizing a suggestion from below:

```
var_dump($_POST['Input_row']);

foreach ($Rows as $Columns) {        
 foreach ($Columns as $column){
   echo $column.',';
 }
 echo "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 for a well-formatted and detailed question, but I am not sure I understand the 'number' and 'letters' stuff - I can't see that in your `var_dump`. A wider point though, can we see how you are creating your CSV lines? Make sure you are using [this standard PHP function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), which will do it for you!

Comment: (By the way, I am curious: I occasionally see posts like this, in which `<br/><br/>` are used to create paragraph breaks. Are you writing these in manually? Just enter return-return, it'll do the same thing!)

Comment: Just one foreach loop, and use fputcsv()... that eliminates any need for a second loop because you write the whole row/line in one call, and also ensures that you won't have problems with writing homebrew CSV writer code

Comment: @halfer I edited the question, regarding your question about the [numbers] element in the question. about the <br /><br />... I have no good explanation or excuse.. just weird I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $file=fopen(<DIRECTORY_PATH>."file.csv","w");
    if(!$file){
       //error
    }

    $csv_data="";
    $i=0;
    foreach($x as $row){
     $i++;
     foreach($row as $element){
        $csv_data.="row-".$i."-".$element.", ";
     }
    //remove the last comma
    $csv_data.="\n";

    }

    fwrite($file,$csv_data);

$query="load data infile '".<DIRECTORY_PATH>."file.csv"."' into table your_table";
if(!mysqli->query($query))
 printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
```

Comment: I put the DB insert just in case you want to import the .csv into DB later.

Comment: Consider what happens if string `$element` contains a comma.

Answer (score 0):

to access the individual values you put the two loops like this

```
foreach ($Rows as $Columns) {        
 foreach ($Columns as $column){
   echo $column.',';
 }
 echo "\r\n";
}
```

if you want a csv, you could so something like this:

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($Rows as $Columns) {        
    fputcsv($fp, $Columns);
}

fclose($fp);
```